# how to get permalink using sql

Tags: posts, permalinks, sql

I am trying to get post title by sql. My sql code is

```
$query ="SELECT     wp_posts.post_title AS title , 
                    wp_posts.post_content AS content,
                    wp_posts.post_date AS blogdate 
        FROM wp_posts
        WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
        ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC ";
global $wpdb;
$result= $wpdb->get_results($query);


 if ($result){

    foreach($result as $post){
    ?><li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php echo $post->title; ?></a></li><?php
    }
 }else{
     echo "Sorry, No Post Found.";
 }

    die();
```

Now the problem is I am getting title but the_permalink() is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using a custom query and not `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` as you should.

Anyway, you need to get the post ID …

```
$query ="SELECT     wp_posts.post_title AS title , 
                    wp_posts.post_content AS content,
                    wp_posts.post_date AS blogdate ,
                    wp_posts.ID AS ID
```

And then just pass this ID to `get_permalink()`:

```
get_permalink( $post->ID );
```

Similar for the title attribute:

```
the_title_attribute( [ 'post' => $post->ID ] );
```

Comment: You may also use `<?php the_permalink( $post->ID ) ?>` from WordPress 4.4.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question on how to get the permalink using purely SQL.

Comment: @Flimm Because that's possible. The final permalink depends on factors outside of the database. They are simply not accessible for SQl. :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely late for the party, but maybe it'll be still useful for someone.

So to get default functions like the_permalink(), the_ID(), etc., you need to first instantiate the post, but **make sure to reset the postdata after you're done** with the current post.

```
setup_postdata( $post: Object || int);

//Do something

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Otherwise you could use get_the_permalink($post) function, most of the functions that start with **the_** have an alternative **get_the** which require $post argument.

Answer (score -1):

Let's see...

```
select p.post_title Title, p.post_date TimeStamp, (SELECT MIN(meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='PermaLink' AND post_id = p.ID) AS PermaLink 
  from wp_terms
  inner join wp_term_taxonomy on wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
  inner join wp_term_relationships wpr on wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
  inner join wp_posts p on p.ID = wpr.object_id 
  /* addidtional conditions - update for your needs */
   where taxonomy= 'category' and p.post_type = 'post' and wp_terms.name = 'News' and p.post_status = 'publish' 
   order by post_date DESC;
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Keep in mind that a good answer includes some level of explanation of *why* this answers the question.  Just posting code doesn't explain anything.